# RethinkDB generic repository in typescript, return promise result from method

Tags: typescript, generics, repository-pattern, rethinkdb, rethinkdb-javascript

I'm trying to write a RethinkDB generic repository in typescript.
I saw that RethinkDB javascript returns promises, I'd like to, for example in GetAll method, return the array items. For the moment I wrote something like this:

```
public GetAll(): T[] {
    this.db.GetConnection().then(connection => {
        this.db.GetTable(this.tableName).run(connection).then(cursor => {
            cursor.toArray<T>().then(items => {
                return items;
            });
        });
    });
}
```

But I get an error in the first line on T[]: A function whose declared type is neither 'void' nor 'any' must return a value.

How can I return an array of T from this method?

Answer (score 0):

Since the results you need to return is coming from a `Promise` (i.e. returned asynchronously), your method also needs to return a `Promise`:

```js
public GetAll(): Promise<T[]> {
    return this.db.GetConnection().then(connection => {
        return this.db.GetTable(this.tableName).run(connection).then(cursor => {
            return cursor.toArray<T>();
        });
    });
}
```

This syntax can be improved a lot using TypeScript's async/await support:

```js
public async GetAll(): Promise<T[]> {
    let connection = await this.db.GetConnection();
    let table = this.db.GetTable(this.tableName);
    let cursor = table.run(connection);
    return await cursor.toArray<T>();
}
```